# How to convert pyc (python compiled file) to java?

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jython

I have a python script 'simplepythonagent.py' that defines a class `SimplePyAgent`, and I'm trying to invoke the class in a Java program. In my Java program, I invoke similar classes by calling `agent.setAgent(new agents.ExampleJavaAgent());`. I'm able to compile 'simplepythonagent.py' to 'simplepythonagent.pyc', but it does not become 'simplepythonagent.java', not does it show up in Eclipse at all. How can I get a class defined in a .pyc to become a .java?

Extra details: I compile .py to .pyc with `>>> import compileall` and then `>>> compileall_compile_dir('pythonscripts')`. I'm doing this because jythonc is no longer supported.

Info: I'm using Eclipse Luna on a mac osx 10.9, with java version 1.7 and python version 2.7.

UPDATE: I am alternatively able to compile with `>>> jython -m compileall /path/to/pythonscripts` which results in 'simplepythonagent$py.class'. How can I get this .class file to show up in Eclipse as a .java file?

Comment: Python isn't meant to compile to Java. You can run python within a JVM, but I don't think you'll find something that takes python bytecode (a `.pyc` file) and decompiles it to Java source code (a `.java`) in one step. It's not that it's undoable per se, it's that I doubt anybody has wanted to. What are you trying to actually accomplish? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

Comment: You won't get a java/class file however in your java code you can use JythonObjectFactory to instantiate Python objects. Look at code listing 10-7 in the manual: http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html
You need to define the Java type for the Python class yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decompiling (many decompilers available) from .class would work, but then the .java file is just compiled again. For my purposes this is redundant. I've opted to create a [jython object factory](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#object-factories). It's straightforward to implement and can be generalized to use over and over for all my python scripts in the project :)